# php CURL not show any response

Tags: php, curl

My code is:

```
<?php
extract($_POST);
$url = "http://www.domain.com/";

$fields = array(
                    'myparam1' => 'something',
                );

foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
rtrim($fields_string, '&');


//open connection
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
//curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
print_r("+");
curl_close($ch);

?>
```

The problem is it show the response in the web browse , but i dont want to. any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The option CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER will return the output rather than printing it.

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a comment on this line:

```
//curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);
```

You should enable this line and set the value to **true**

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```

As you can see on the man page [here](http://php.net/curl_setopt) that option is used this way:

> TRUE to return the transfer as a string of the return value of
>   curl_exec() instead of outputting it out directly.

Answer (score 0):

`CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` can take `array` directly  and `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` should be `true`

```
$url = "http://www.php.net";
$fields = array(
        'myparam1' => 'something'
);
// open connection
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this url will help you.

[Get data or Content from a URL using cURL PHP](http://phpcodeforbeginner.blogspot.in/2013/01/get-data-or-content-from-url-using-curl.html)